# How do I download every Gmail email with Python?

Tags: python, google-api, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

I want to download them with as few API calls as possible. https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/tree/master/samples doesn't have Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

Start by following [Python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) it will give you an idea of how to get the Auth part working

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
    Lists the user's Gmail labels.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Gmail API
    results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
    labels = results.get('labels', [])

    if not labels:
        print('No labels found.')
    else:
        print('Labels:')
        for label in labels:
            print(label['name'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Once you understand what that is doing you should be able to consult [user message list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list) to get an idea of how to alter it for listing a messages.